# how can I sync data between multiple tomcat instances

Tags: java, tomcat

I want to store my data in java static variables. like store autoCode in Map

```
private static final PassiveExpiringMap<String, String> authCodeMap = new PassiveExpiringMap<>(1000 * 60 * 60);
```

how can I sync data between multiple tomcat instances

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use an in memory cache that runs as an external service like [redis](http://redis.io/) or [Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.com/) to store the data. I would suggest to use Hazelcast, because you are using Java.